# Auto-Format String Python

Tags: python, formatting, output

How can I automatically format a string in Python?

I'm trying to print the remainders of pascal's triangle modulo seven, up to a row number specified by the user. Furthermore, I want it to be properly centered. For example, if the number of rows to be printed is 20, then I would print

```
print('{:^41}'.format(row_x))
```

For each row x<=20.

But, like I said above, I want the number of rows to change. I've tried

```
print('{:^'+str(rownumber*2 +1)'+'}'.format(row_x))
```

As well as

```
print('{:^rownumber*2 +1}'.format(row_x))
```

Both of which give me an error. What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Try `print(('{:^'+str(rownumber*2 +1)'+'}').format(row_x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't work if inserted into the formatting area for some reason so use instead:

```
 >>> x = 20
 >>> a = '{:^' + str(2*x+1) + '}'
 >>> print(a.format(x))
 >>>                   20
```